# jquery doesn't work after upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I designed a website on my Computer with XAMP, but as I uploaded it to my Host all the Javascript and Jquery just stopped working.

the only Error I get back looks like this

```
$("#link1").FontEffect is not a function
```

All the required .js files are imported. And my script looks like this:

```
<script src="./script/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./script/menu.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="./script/shadow.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>    
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./script/jquery-FontEffect-1.0.0.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#wrapper").boxshadow(20,20,100,'#30302F');
   $("#link1").FontEffect({outline:true, shadow:true ,shadowColor:'#414345' ,outlineColor1:'#A06BB5', outlineWeight:2, shadowBlur:2})
   $("#link2").FontEffect({outline:true, shadow:true ,shadowColor:'#414345' ,outlineColor1:'#26A31A', outlineWeight:2, shadowBlur:2})
   $("#link3").FontEffect({outline:true, shadow:true ,shadowColor:'#414345' ,outlineColor1:'#E81515', outlineWeight:2, shadowBlur:2})
   $("#link4").FontEffect({outline:true, shadow:true ,shadowColor:'#414345' ,outlineColor1:'#DB641A', outlineWeight:2, shadowBlur:2})
   $("#link5").FontEffect({outline:true, shadow:true ,shadowColor:'#414345' ,outlineColor1:'#4D5154', outlineWeight:2, shadowBlur:2})
   $("#kwicks").kwicks({
  max:205,  
  min:25,  
  spacing:1
  });
   $(function () {
  $("#navi > li a").hover( function () { $(this).stop().animate({paddingLeft : '25px'}, 500);
  }, function () {$(this).animate({paddingLeft : '10px'}, 400);});
 });
 });
   </script>
```

Thannks for your help!

Comment: none of the funcions work anymore not even the simple animate()

Comment: Check if the fonteffect js file is actually loaded.

Comment: I checked that could it be that it isnt found because of a case difference in the import?

Comment: that was it the path and all was correct I just had a Case difference in the scriptname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file is called `jquery-FontEffect-1.0.0.min.js` and not `jquery-fonteffect-1.0.0.min.js` or `jquery-FONTEFFECT-1.0.0.min.js`. Case does matter in Unix servers.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked case sensitivity in your path to the js files?

Answer (score 0):

are you correctly linking to jquery and any plugins?

your html source is equally as important.

and that error suggests it can't find the right file from my experience

Answer (score 0):

FontEffect is a jQuery plugin.
Test in order:

- All the libraries are correctly linked
- You load jQuery and then FontEffect

Answer (score 0):

Can it be possible that paths to jQuery and other Js files are incorrect?

Can I suggest you trying "http://url/script/jqueryxys.js" from the browser?

Comment: thats not the problem all the js files are linked with the right path and are actually on the server

Answer (score 0):

Use the FF extension firebug, load the site and navigate to the network tab. You should see all requests and there should be four requests for including the js files. Check if they are red. If they are, the server can't find the files located at that address, meaning the paths are wrong.

Comment: You would have seen that the path to the one jquery library wasn't right.